# Magento2 : Recommended way to properly filter the logs?

Tags: magento2, configuration, log, magento2.3.0

Recommended way to properly filter the logs?

It's like a log4j Java app with every logger active, so essentially a flood of useless chatter.  Is there any way I can configure or manage what gets logged?  Mabye set a level threshold?  Or even disable certain loggers?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up throwing this script in the project bin/, and use it to start PHP's built-in webserver.

```
#!/bin/sh

MAGE_DIR="${MAGE_DIR:-$(readlink -m "${0}/../../")}"
cd "$MAGE_DIR" || { 
    echo "cd $MAGE_DIR failed"
    exit 1
}

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT


php -S localhost:8082 -t ./pub/ phpserver/router.php & 
PID=$!

tail -f --pid $PID var/log/system.log | grep -v '\(DEBUG\|INFO\)'
```

I'd still like to know how to properly configure logs, or if Magento even has such a capability.